# SPO: Show loading gif on Page until Datatable has loaded completely and is clickable

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ui, datatable, boot-strap

I have a Datatable on a Page that takes around 7-10 seconds to load. I have a loader script that initiates a loader gif when the page is first visited, but the loader gif fades out well before all of the datatable is loaded. I cannot figure out why this happens.

Is it possible for the loading gif  to display on the screen until the entirety of the datatable is loaded and clickable? Then, once the datatable has fully loaded, the loading gif should disappear. I've included the datatable script as well as the loader script I'm currebntly using that isn't working.

#### Datatables Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    loadMyItems();  
});  

function loadMyItems() {  
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;  
    var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyLibrary')/items?$select=ID,Title&$top=5000";  
    $.ajax({  
        url: oDataUrl,  
        type: "GET",  
        dataType: "json",  
        headers: {  
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: mySuccHandler,  
        error: myErrHandler  
    });  
}  

function mySuccHandler(data) {  
    try {  
        var dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable();  
        if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {  
            dataTableExample.destroy();  
        }  
        dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable({  
         <!-- scrollY: 800, -->  
            "aaData": data.d.results,  
                "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "ID"  
            }, {      
                "mData": "Title"  
            }]  
        });  
    } 
catch (e) {  
        alert(e.message);  
    }  
}
```

#### Loader JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
// preloader
    $(window).ready(function(){
    $('#preloader').delay(100).fadeOut(1000);
    $('#overlay').delay(400).fadeOut(1000);
})

}(jQuery));
</script>
```

#### Loader CSS

```
.spinner {
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                border: 2px solid #103c6d;
                border-top: solid #EF4931;
                border-left:dotted #ffd300;
                border-bottom: solid #B9CEC5;
                border-radius: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: auto;
                animation: spin .4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
                from {
                                transform: rotate(0deg);
                }
                to {
                                transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
}
#overlay {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables emits [events](https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/) which you can listen for.  In particular, you could listen for the `draw` event which fires when the table is done drawing.

So you could do something like

```
function mySuccHandler(data) {
    try {
        var dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable();
        if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {
            dataTableExample.destroy();
        }

        // using one() here instead of on() will ensure
        // that the attempt to remove the loader
        // will only happen after this initial table draw
        $('#table_id').one('draw.dt', function() {
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
        });

        dataTableExample = $('#table_id').DataTable({  
            <!-- scrollY: 800, -->
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "ID"
            }, {
                "mData": "Title"
            }]  
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the most part. The loading gif freezes after 1-2 seconds BEFORE the data is loaded, BUT the frozen gif remains visible until the page is fully loaded. If there's a quick fix for this, I'm interested, if not, I won't look a gift horse in the mouth...

Comment: @TheJDScott from what you posted it looks like the loading animation is controlled through CSS animation, which I am not very familiar with, sorry.